# Tapping a metal pipe into a metal bore

Tags: mechanical-engineering

If I would like to insert a metal tube (tap on it with a hammer),half-way, into a metal bore, what should be the difference between the outside diameter of the tube and the inside diameter of the bore, so the tube will fit tight to the bore walls?

Comment: Define "tight"? I can use a 15lb sledge and force an interference fit if I chamfer the "internal" pipe...

Comment: One way is to cool the inside pipe and/or ,heat the outer pipe.

Comment: @Solar Mike.When i say tight,i mean that the metal tube will be able to be tapped,half way,inside the bore with an hammer without damaging the bore walls and it can be tapped out in the future to be replaced.The metal tube is a mild steel metal,while the bore is cast-iron.The amount of"tight"should be enough that liquid will not pass between them.My question is referred to the diameter difference values.

Comment: @blacksmith37.I am interesting about the diameter difference rather than the method.

Comment: You will need a tenths micrometer to measure both. The bore would have to be undersized or the shaft oversized by a a few tenths (of thousandth of an inch, (0.0001"). Maybe two or three. That's around the amount common metals will easily deform by. That's for a good smooth finish. The deeper you go the greater the force is due to contact area. You say half way but that says nothing because half of what? Press fitting into a bore that is only 1" deep is very different from one that is 5" deep. The first section might go in reasonably but tapping it deeper might take a *much* bigger hammer.

Comment: But I have my doubts about being able to make it removeable and replaceable without damage. The materials are likely to gall over time without anti-seize grease which would contaminate things since it's carrying liquid. It's also a pipe so much more vulnerable to damage from hitting it than a solid pin, even moreso if it's longer than a pin which it probably is if it's carrying liquids. Have you also thought about the punch that would be required to tap it out (or in for that matter) without damage? And (how to access it if it is a closed container)?

Comment: Could you provide dimensions of the pipe, bore and the surroundings of the bore?

Comment: @DKNguyen,in regards to the size of the metal tube,it is 55mm length and 30mm diameter(1.5mm thick),which should be inserted about halfway(~25mm)into the bore.And in regards to removing part,it doesn't matter if the metal tube will be damaged during the remove,since i will insert a new one,the main concern is that it won't stuck in the bore and i will be able to remove it easily with no special issue.To tap it in i can use a hammer and a piece of wood.To tap it out,i am not sure.

Comment: @Tomas Letal,the question is about the dimensions.

Comment: Tight requires one to answer how tight?  I usually think of it as able to resist slip from 1/5 force from pressure of compression for metal:metal.  You can then get to stress from the pressure, strain from the stress, and finally the deflection you'll need to induce

Comment: @DKNguyen,as you mentioned,it is closed container and i will not have much access to remove it in the future.If half of the metal tube(the half that is outside the bore) will corrode and break and the other half(which is inside the bore)will remain inside,do you have a simple method to remove the half tube that stuck inside the bore?(i don't care to ruin the tube,but without damage the bore)

Comment: @xchcui Well, you're kind of lucky since your tube is so big and thin. You might be able to just get a hand saw in there to cut split the pipe. The other alternative is to make a device long mandrel that goes into the bore and expands a bit to catch the inside the lip of the tube. The outside end of the mandrel has an enlarged head that captivates a big block of steel that you slide back quickly to hammer against. It's like a reverse mallet that you pull. Or make a similar device that works like a gear puller but for an inside bore.

Answer (score 2):

## Tube-in-tube elastic shrink-fit

This problem can be simplified to a shrink-fit of tube in tube using Lamé equations for thick cylinder elastic deformation.
Radial deflection of the tube will be:

$$u(r) = C_{a1}\cdot r+\frac{C_{a2}}{r}$$

and functions for radial and tangential stress components:

$$\sigma_r(u) = \frac{E}{1-\mu_a^2}\cdot \left((1+\mu_a)\cdot C_{a1}-\frac{1-\mu_a}{r^2}\cdot C_{a2}\right)$$
$$\sigma_t(u) = \frac{E}{1-\mu_a^2}\cdot \left((1+\mu_a)\cdot C_{a1}+\frac{1-\mu_a}{r^2}\cdot C_{a2}\right)$$

### Boundary conditions

Calculating stresses for a known setup requires 4 conditions for calculating $C_i$ for both tubes;

- radial stress in equilibrium with pressure $P_i$ at the internal surface of internal tube
- radial stress in equilibrium with pressure $P_o$ at the external surface of external tube
- radial stress equilibrium in the contact between the tubes
- difference between radial displacements of tubes at the contact between them ($r_{ao}-r_{bi}=\delta$, the overlap)

These conditions can be mathematically described by a system of linear equations:

$$\left[\begin{matrix} 1+\mu_a & -\frac{1-\mu_a}{r_{ai}^2} & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1+\mu_b & -\frac{1-\mu_b}{r_{bo}^2} \\
\frac{E_a}{1-\mu_a} & -\frac{E_a}{\left(1+\mu_a\right)\cdot r_{ao}^2} & -\frac{E_b}{1-\mu_b} & \frac{E_b}{\left(1+\mu_b\right)\cdot r_{bi}^2} \\
r_{ao} & \frac{1}{r_{ao}} & -r_{bi} & -\frac{1}{r_{bi}} \end{matrix}\right] \cdot
\left[\begin{matrix}\color{crimson}{C_{a1}} \\ \color{crimson}{C_{a2}} \\ \color{crimson}{C_{b1}} \\ \color{crimson}{C_{b2}}\end{matrix}\right] =
\left[\begin{matrix}-P_i\cdot \frac{1-\mu_a^2}{E_a} \\ -P_o\cdot \frac{1-\mu_b^2}{E_b} \\ 0 \\ r_{bi}-r_{ao}\end{matrix}\right]$$

where:

- $r_{ai}$ and $r_{ao}$ are inside and outside radii of the internal tube,
- $E_a$ and $\mu_a$ are Youngs modulus and Poisson ratio of the internal tube,
- $P_i$ is internal pressure (can be zero)
- parameters with subscript "b" are for "external" tube, which models the plate with the bore

### Extreme case with infinite plate

The inside tube stress will be the higher the more stiff the plate will be. You can assume, that the worst case scenario is plate with infinite outside diameter, where the radial stress is zero, for which $C_{b1}$ has to be zero, so the system of equations is simplified:

$$\left[\begin{matrix} 1+\mu_a & -\frac{1-\mu_a}{r_{ai}^2} & 0 \\
\frac{E_a}{1-\mu_a} & -\frac{E_a}{\left(1+\mu_a\right)\cdot r_{ao}^2} & \frac{E_b}{\left(1+\mu_b\right)\cdot r_{bi}^2} \\
r_{ao} & \frac{1}{r_{ao}} & -\frac{1}{r_{bi}} \end{matrix}\right] \cdot
\left[\begin{matrix}\color{crimson}{C_{a1}} \\ \color{crimson}{C_{a2}} \\ \color{crimson}{C_{b2}}\end{matrix}\right] =
\left[\begin{matrix}-P_i\cdot \frac{1-\mu_a^2}{E_a} \\ 0 \\ r_{bi}-r_{ao}\end{matrix}\right]$$

Stress distribution may look like this:
[image]

From this, you can calculate dependence of extreme tube and bore stresses (tangential on internal surfaces), here for $\mu_a=\mu_b=0.3$, $E_a=200 GPa$ and $E_b=118 GPa$. There is also cooling which you would require to fit the tube without hammer for coefficient of thermal expansion $11e-6 K^{-1}$ (minimum same temperature fitting force could be calculated using radial contact stress, coefficient of friction and contact area):

[image]

A good thing is, that bore stress is much smaller than tube stress.

### Disclaimer

For tightness, you need continuous contact with some contact pressures, which would require precision to achieve. This may be even harder after first disassembly, when the bore surface may get damaged with axial scratches, which are the worst for the tightness.

Presented model is axisymmetric, so any deviation from that will lead to deviations in reality. This will be probably most pronounced in plate shape around the bore, which will lead to uneven stress distribution around tube circumference.